# byte array to something I can read in PHP

Tags: c#, php, json

I'm building/working with an API and I make a call to the server and get a JSON object back.  Now, the thing I get back is an array of bytes.  Eventually, it will be an image, I just have to figure out how the heck to turn it from an array of bytes into an image...and I have no idea where to even begin with it.  On the server, this was C# that created this array, now it's in my PHP code...where do I start?

Yes, I have been googling around and came up with basically implode()'ing the array into a string and using the imagefromstring() function, but that throws an error that it's not a recognized format.  So I'm really not sure if this is my error, or I'm using the wrong function/going down the wrong path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the format of the image sent to you from the server? Is it encoded on the server as well? Perhaps base64 or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have to guess, then your "array of bytes" is really a list of integers in the JSON object. If so, you can probably convert it back into the original binary data using:

```
$bin = implode("", array_map("chr", $json_array));
```

And then try `imagecreatefromstring`.

Comment: That did the trick....I was thinking of this as bytes, but this was just a bunch of integers.  Thanks for your help